# What is a Sauce course?

Tags: sauce

According to the article on [Full course dinners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_course_dinner) on Wikipedia, the third course of a [five course meal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_course_dinner#5_course_meal) is "Sauce":

> 1. Entrée
> 2. Main Course
> 3. **Sauce**
> 4. Dessert
> 5. Cigars

I'm having trouble finding what exactly this is and how one makes a sauce into a course. What sort of sauce is it? Is there something else served with it, or is it just pots and spoons? Other than Nachos and Salsa I can't picture it, and that doesn't sound like a staple of fine dining.

Comment: There are no references for that on the wikipedia page, so I would not make that official..

Comment: ...and it says the fifth course is "cigars". That *really* does not look like a legitimate standard meal plan to me, and answering your question is probably more about figuring out where that came from than anything meaningful about what people actually eat.

Comment: @Jefromi I suppose in retrospect it is a bit silly, maybe it's tiredness or maybe it's all the old fashioned / cliched movies I've seen but Brandy & Cigars just slipped by as not that 'out there' when you're talking about a 5 course meal.

Comment: Yeah, I can certainly see *some* people doing that, but as an ostensibly canonical example of a five-course meal, maybe a little off :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's almost certainly made up. A user who has edited nothing else on Wikipedia added it in [this revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Full_course_dinner&diff=754743310&oldid=754554753). There has been a lot of other vandalism in [the full history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Full_course_dinner&action=history), some of it caught and reverted, some not.

Cigars were added in [this revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Full_course_dinner&diff=755686107&oldid=755285691) by an anonymous user, and someone helpfully capitalized it (rather than reverting, sigh) in [this revision](http://but%20didn't%20revert,%20sigh).

Without any sources cited, it's pretty difficult to tell whose version of the five-course meal this was supposed to be, but for what it's worth, before the "sauce" and "cigars" vandalism, the courses were soup, fish, main course, dessert, and cheese, which sounds pretty sane to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since cigars is on the menu, I would guess sauce is slang for a cocktail/alcohol.  More context would definitely help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's some kind of typo for "salad". Maybe somebody wrote it out in illegible (maybe even cursive) handwriting or something, and that's how it got in there.